# Add the word "cant" to Spacy stopwords

Tags: python, spacy

How to I get `SpaCy` to set words such as "cant" and "wont" as stopwords?
For example, even with tokenisation it will identify "can't" as a stop word, but not "cant".
When it sees "cant", it removes "ca" but leaves "nt". Is it by design? I guess "nt" is not really a word.

Here is a sample code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = "cant can't cannot"
doc = nlp(text)

for word in doc:
    print(word,":",word.is_stop)

ca : True
nt : False
ca : True
n't : True
can : True
not : True
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen with en-core-web-trf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Spacy's documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#tokenization), the tokenizer cannot add or remove information to the text, so you would always be able to reconstruct the same input text (using the whitespace information stored inside the `Token`s). This also means that if the text contains spelling errors, they will be kept.

So, there is no error in the tokenization process, since Spacy splits constructs such as *can't* or *don't* into two different tokens: *do* and *n't*, for example.

*cant* and *wont* are two spelling errors (actually, they are actual English words, that Spacy "is able to recognize" as auxiliaries and it then splits them as it would split *can't* or *won't*). We could say that the split is correct and that it follows the rule it would follow with the correct version of these words, the only problem there is consists in recognizing *wo* and *nt* as stopwords. You can see [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/stop_words.py) the list of stopwords used by Spacy; for example, *ca* is present and that is why it is correctly recognized as a stopword (*n't* is added at the end among the contractions).

If the split is ok for your use case, you can add *wo* and *nt* manually to the list of stopwords.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

my_stop_words = ["nt", "wo"]
STOP_WORDS.update(my_stop_words)
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# analyze docs
```

If, for some reason, you need to do something with the stopwords in your text and you'd like to have *wont* and *cant* and not *wo*, *nt* and *ca*, *nt*, you could think about concatenating consecutive stopwords by checking if the trailing whitespace is empty (meaning that the tokens were attached in the original text):

```py
stop_words_in_text = []
doc = nlp("Today I cant go to work. We wont come to your party.")

for token in doc:
    i = token.i
    if token.is_stop:
        if i > 0 and doc[i-1].whitespace_ == "" and doc[i-1].is_stop:
            stop_words_in_text[-1] += token.text
        else:
            stop_words_in_text.append(token.text)

print(stop_words_in_text)

['I', 'cant', 'go', 'to', 'We', 'wont', 'to', 'your']
```

Hopefully, this will help you. You can also implement custom Spacy components and check [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases) if you need to add special tokenization cases.

Answer (score 1):

The tokenizer splits "cant" into "ca" and "nt". Adding "cant" to the list won't surge any effect because not token will be matched. Instead "nt" should be added as in the example (3rd line of code).

Also it is important to update the stopwords before loading the model, otherwise if won't pick the changes.

Example:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

STOP_WORDS.add("nt")

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = "cant can't cannot"
doc = nlp(text)

for word in doc:
    print(word,":",word.is_stop)
```

```
ca : True
nt : True
ca : True
n't : True
can : True
not : True
```